# why does the compiler subtract value on ESP

Tags: gcc, elf

Look at this code I've disassemble a simple portion of a c program, compile with gcc in 32 bits mode.
As you can see, the compiler subtract 8 on ESP, then subtract 0xC. The push is subtracting 4 bytes on ESP. So before the printf call, we have 24 bytes allocated on the stack.

```
  0x0804846e <+3>:  sub    esp,0x8
  0x08048471 <+6>:  sub    esp,0xc
  0x08048474 <+9>:  push   0x8048550
  0x08048479 <+14>: call   0x8048330 <printf@plt>
  0x0804847e <+19>: add    esp,0x10
```

But, if you look after the printf call, the compiler only adds 16 bytes. So i think there is a leak ?

If i want to write by myself in assembler, i would write:

```
  0x08048474 <+9>:  push   0x8048550
  0x08048479 <+14>: call   0x8048330 <printf@plt>
  0x0804847e <+19>: add    esp,0x4
```

Do you think i am wrong ? What is the goal of allocating data on stack with sub esp if there is no local variable ?

Comment: Checking whether the stack pointer is restored to the correct value is easy. After this function returns, does the execution continue as it should in the caller? If it does, then the return address was found. The return address will almost certainly not be found if the stack pointer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the goal of allocating data on stack with sub esp if there is no local variable ?

Often it's stack alignment: GCC doesn't know whether called routine uses SSE2 instructions that require alignment, so it keeps stack aligned to 16 bytes within the routine.

> i think there is a leak

Most likely there isn't. But you didn't show the entire disassembly, so it's impossible to tell.